# Issue embedding my Google Calendar Appointment Schedule button in Elementor

Tags: javascript, google-calendar-api, elementor

I am blocked, trying to add the following embed code, to add an appointment schedule button on my website with Elementor :

```
<!-- Google Calendar Appointment Scheduling begin -->
<link href="https://calendar.google.com/calendar/scheduling-button-script.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script>
(function() {
  var target = document.currentScript;
  window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    calendar.schedulingButton.load({
      url: 'https://calendar.google.com/calendar/appointments/schedules/AcZssZ3ULC2u1RPwVOg78x3Xte5R2Kiboz8Zxop9jvQ5LJxVn2thdV8TzfIdTyNhs27HP2biG3d8OSqA?gv=true',
      color: '#e45724',
      label: "Book a discovery meet",
      target,
    });
  });
})();
</script>
<!-- end Google Calendar Appointment Scheduling -->
```

I tried to put the embed code in a HTML element, but it shows the button only after the whole page (in the code, it is displayed in the scripts)
[button & code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IhffJ.png)

So it seems like the position of the script itself is problematic here.

I tried to put the first script after header (in theme header.php), but then the button doesn't load at all.

I'm not very fluent in javascript, so I'm blocked, not sure how I can fix that.

/!-!\ Unfortunately, I can't setup a staging environment to show the page directly, as Elementor doesn't update with this embed code on staging (wonderful Bluehost) /!-!\

Comment: What errors does your console show?  If JS is breaking somewhere above your Google script .. Your Google script will not fire correctly.  We need more debugging info here.

Answer (score -1):

My bad, I've been able to find the source of the issue.

This was caused by the feature "Defer Non-Essential JavaScript" of Jetpack Boost apparently, as it is now correctly located after I disable it.

Now, the next issue is : how could I force jetpack to execute the code instead of defer it?

the script indicate async, so it shouldn't be defer right?

Comment: You'll need to ask a new question for your follow-up, rather than putting it inside your answer. Could you also post some code, documentation, or steps on how to disable the troublesome feature?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).